# Is there any feature in MySQL to perform query only on last inserted row in a table?

Tags: mysql, database, row, query-optimization, temp-tables

I need to validate the last inserted row in a table every time using some constraints given by the user on a particular column in that table( Ex: age > 50...etc.).

I thought of using a temporary table to insert the row in both of my temporary table and my normal table. After then, I'll use query like Select * from tb_name USER_CONSTRAINTS [ Ex: select * from student where age>50 ] on temporary table. If the result is not null, then the last row satisfies the user constraint else it fails. After I'll delete the last added row from the temporary table and repeat the process for next row.

I don't know if this way is good or bad or is there some other efficient way to do this?

Edit:
The table has 5 columns

```
stud_id, 
subject_id, 
age, 
dob, 
marks
```

Here stud_id and subject_id act as foreign keys to two tables tbl_student and tbl_subject

Comment: Is my method of doing any good or efficient?

Comment: `WHERE blablabla ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` Assuming `id` is an autoincrement

Comment: @RiggsFolly what if id is not auto-increment?

Comment: Then that wont work :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is there some other way?

Comment: Maybe if you tell us more about the table in question we can be a bit more productive :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233358/discussion-between-crox-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: @RiggsFolly can we continue this in discussion?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've added the table information in my question

Comment: _Small Note_ An age column will be out of date any time from 1 day after entered to 364 days after enetered. In short its at best useless and at worst dangerous. You have a DOB so an age is calulatable any day you like and will be accurate

Comment: A database table is a bag -- an unordered set -- of rows. Once a row's inserted it is just one of the rows in the table. If you want to manipulate the last row inserted you must have some kind of `WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT` scheme to find it first. Or you could try using a [`BEFORE INSERT` trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).